# Multiple fancyboxes on a page | Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, fancybox, webforms

I need to have **3 different Fancyboxes** with **different content**.

Have no trouble "**triggering**" the Fancybox on click but my issue is how can I associate a **web form** or **usercontrol** to the Fancybox if that makes sense?

***Example***: Say a user clicks on an anchor named "**add to basket**". I need the corresponding Fancybox with the appropriate content to render on click. What I don't know is:

1. Do I need to use another **web form** for the content?
2. Do I need to use a **usercontrol** for the content?
3. How to get fancybox to **recognize** which **web form** or **usercontrol** to
   render according to which ever anchor the user clicks on as there
   will be **multiple instances of different fancyboxes**... again, if that
   makes sense.

Comment: No one has done this before?!?

Comment: Well, this question is unanswerable to me. Try asking more specific questions.